# Unable to display progress dialog in android

Tags: android, android-studio, progressdialog

I am trying to show progress dialog but it's not showing on my mobile screen.

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
progressDialog.setMessage("Checking Meter Status....");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

In the android developer documentation for [dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs),

> Caution: Android includes another dialog class called [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog) that shows a dialog with a progress bar. This widget is deprecated because it prevents users from interacting with the app while progress is being displayed. If you need to indicate loading or indeterminate progress, you should follow the design guidelines for [Progress & Activity](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress) and use a [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) in your layout, instead of using [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog).

As a matter of fact it is always recommended to follow guidelines issued in the developer documentation, so you should also do the same.